# Pulling changes made in Umbraco back office to local host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, umbraco

So I'm tinkering with using Umbraco as a CMS for an MVC application. Of course, I run the site locally and publish to a server and use Umbraco for managing things like hero images, carousel text, and a few basic dynamic elements that are stored in Umbraco.

However, one can also modify the actual template .cshtml files as well through the Umbraco back office. The problem with that is that those changes won't be reflected locally, and any changes made in the Umbraco back office would get overwritten on the next publish.

Is there any way to 'pull' the changes made in Umbraco (without having to FTP in and download the entire site), or even better integrate it with git directly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, Umbraco uSync package might help you:
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/

It exports the changes in "uSync" folder locally - you can do this automatically or manually, and then you transfer those files on the server, and do import within Umbraco Dev section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use uSync for this but you should probably decide whether you edit your template files locally or on the server.  Generally you would probably keep editing template files, CSS, js, locally and upload changes to your live site.  However, if you are adding content, setting up a template for the first time, changing doc types, adding data types etc, these are all database changes so either; share the database on the server between your local and Server versions of the site; or use a tool like Courier or USync to replicate your changes between environments.